# how do i track key presses and log them to the console in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

lately, I've started making a very simple program that I what to basically be a bunch of hotkeys for different JavaScript tags. But I don't know how to track the key presses and log them into the console.

Comment: There are event listeners you can add to the DOM that listen for keypress, keyup, and keydown.

Comment: Please do some simple research before asking.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML

```
<input type="text" id="username" onkeyup="myFunc()">
```

In Javascript

```
function myFunc(){
    console.log(document.getElementByID('username).value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the whole window (to see the code snippet work, click Run code snippet then click in the blank area below and type some keys :) )

```js
// list of modifiers : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/getModifierState
var modifiers = ["CapsLock", "Control", "Alt", "Shift", "AltGraph"];
var upOrDown = function(event) {
    var element = document.getElementById("status");
    var key = event.key || event.which || event.keyCode; //find the key that was pressed
    var status = "Pressed :";
    for (const modifier of modifiers) {
        if (event.getModifierState(modifier))
        {
            status += " "+modifier;
        }
    }
    if ("keydown"==event.type && !modifiers.includes(key))
    {

        status += " "+key;
    }
    element.innerHTML = status;
    //console.log(status);
}
window.addEventListener("keydown",upOrDown,false);
window.addEventListener("keyup",upOrDown,false);
```

```html
<div id="status">Pressed : </div>
```